# Flink TypeInfo Java Generics

Tags: java, generics, apache-flink

I want my Flink app to deserialize data from a Kafka topic either to Flink stream of `ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]>` or a Flink stream of `Tuple2<byte[], byte[]>` using the Flink `org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2` class.

With both options I can't get a getProducedType implementation that compiles.

```java
public class KafkaNOOPDeserialization implements KafkaDeserializationSchema<ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]>> {
    @Override
    public boolean isEndOfStream(ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> nextElement) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> deserialize(ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> record) throws Exception {
        return record;
    }

    @Override
    public TypeInformation<ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]>> getProducedType() {
        // This provides TypeInformation<ConsumerRecord>
        // It needs TypeInformation<ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]>>
        var typeInfo = TypeExtractor.getForClass(ConsumerRecord.class);
        // This hard cast won't compile
        return (TypeInformation<ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]>>) typeInfo;
    }
}
```

```java
public class KafkaByteArrayTupleDeserializer implements KafkaDeserializationSchema<Tuple2<byte[], byte[]>> {
    @Override
    public boolean isEndOfStream(Tuple2<byte[], byte[]> nextElement) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Tuple2<byte[], byte[]> deserialize(ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> record) throws Exception {
        return new Tuple2(record.key(), record.value());
    }

    @Override
    public TypeInformation<Tuple2<byte[], byte[]>> getProducedType() {
        // This provides TupleTypeInfo<Tuple>
        // It needs TupleTypeInfo<Tuple2<byte[], byte[]>>
        var typeInfo = TupleTypeInfo.getBasicAndBasicValueTupleTypeInfo(
                byte[].class, byte[].class);
        // Hard cast won't compile
        return (TypeInformation<Tuple2<byte[], byte[]>>) typeInfo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flink provides the `org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeHint` class that helps with this. ([documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/typeinfo/TypeHint.html))

For instance in your second example instead of:

```
return (TypeInformation<Tuple2<byte[], byte[]>>) typeInfo;
```

You could write:

```
return new TypeHint<Tuple2<byte[], byte[]>>(){}.getTypeInfo();
```